# remove the address bar and location bar in window.open javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Am opening the aspx page in a popup from Window.open using javascript as below.

```
function OpenPopupWindow() {
        var userWidth = screen.availWidth;
        var userHeight = screen.availHeight;
        leftPos = (userWidth - 500) / 2,
            topPos = (userHeight - 500) / 2;
        settings = 'modal,scrollBars=no,resizable=no,titlebar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,left=' + leftPos + ',top=' + topPos + ',width=500, height=500';
        window.open("EnhanceTerms.aspx", "window", settings);
    }
```

As I expected, the address bar is not showing when i open this page in firefox and IE, but in Chrome it is still showing.

And also how to hide the minimize and maximize from the pop up.

please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You just check the jQuery version that you are using, and put the jQuery Url **just up** on the Java Script Code.

Comment: For the popup aspx page ("EnhanceMaster.aspx"), am not using any Jquery, but for the page where am using this method, am having the Jquery 1.7.2                                                                                                          <script src="Scripts/js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

For safety reasons, most of the browsers today don't allow hiding the address bar anymore.

You cannot remove minimize/maximize buttons form popup as well.

Comment: Is there any alternate you would suggest as am having this requirement need to do ASAP.